# UDP: Why can't you `bind` after a `connect`?

Tags: sockets, udp, bind, connect

This works fine:

```
socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_IP) = 4
setsockopt(4, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, [1], 4) = 0
bind(4, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(4444), sin_addr=inet_addr("0.0.0.0")}, 16) = 0
connect(4, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(0), sin_addr=inet_addr("1.1.1.1")}, 16) = 0
```

And we can observe the proper binding to local and remote:

```
$ sudo lsof -Pni :4444
COMMAND  PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
udpdup  2815 nhed    4u  IPv4 126724      0t0  UDP 10.0.2.15:4444->1.1.1.1:*
```

But putting the connect first, get an error on the bind, why?

```
socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_IP) = 4
setsockopt(4, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, [1], 4) = 0
connect(4, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(0), sin_addr=inet_addr("1.1.1.1")}, 16) = 0
bind(4, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(4444), sin_addr=inet_addr("0.0.0.0")}, 16) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
```

---

Why do I care you ask?

I thought that received packets are matched against a 5-element tuple (proto, loc addr, loc port, rem addr, rem port).  Where some of the 5 can be ANY (a wildcard), indicated numerically as `0` or `0.0.0.0` in `struct sockaddr_in` and often represented often in `netstat`, `lsof`, etc.  The above `lsof` output shows 4/5 elements specified, remote port left as wildcard)

I could not remember if multiple sockets should exists where some had the wildcard peer addr and others could be explicit, sending traffic to the right port based on a best match.

I wanted to experiment and check that when one app has bound a port without specifying the sender address, that another app could connect & bind the peer, to form a more complete tuple.
[note that the first app does not specify `SO_REUSEADDR`]

p.s. could someone with enough points please create a `udp-connect` tag? (and even a udp-bind)

Comment: if you are going to take points (-1) then please comment why

Answer (score 1):

`connect(2)` implicitly binds your local port, so subsequent explicit `bind(2)` fails.

#### Edit 0:

You can bind multiple sockets to the same local port, but all the bindings following the first one must be more specific. Say, first socket is bound to `INADDR_ANY`, and others are to specific addresses of existing network interfaces. Note, that **all** the sockets must be set with `SO_REUSEADDR`.

Then there's multicast, which allows you to create completely duplicate socket bindings, but only to a specific class of addresses, and you have to do a bit more work to set it up.

It also seems to me you are confusing this with TCP listening vs. connected sockets.

#### Edit 1:

`connect(2)` also fixes socket local address according to the route to destination.

Comment: yes, binds an ephemeral local port, so the only way to specify 4/5 is to bind first, and so basically what I'm describing in the last paragraph is not possible?

Comment: be assured that I am not mixing this with TCP.  manpage (2) for connect: "If  the  socket  sockfd is of type SOCK_DGRAM then addr is the address to which datagrams are sent by default, and the only address from which datagrams are received"